# Null point handling in adapter filter

Tags: android, exception, null

Here i am getting java.string.null pointer exception can any one give solution for it.Thanks in advance

```
public void filter(String charText) {

    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    _data.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        _data.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (SelectUser wp : arraylist)
            if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                _data.add(wp);
            }
    }
```

Comment: on which line you are getting it

Comment: Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint and see what variables are null.

Comment: @DinithePieris Much better :D

Comment: every object could throw a nullpointer exception if it is not initialized. So we need to see the stacktrace to know where....